# listen to request before authentication or rewrite /login_check in symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to register an eventListener which would be called before the /login_check tries to login the user.

I'm writing a DDoS protection, iIlog in database each try (date, user_id, is_failure), and if an user has more than N wrong attempts to login, I generate a token sent by email to the right user email. Anyone without this token will be forbidden to try another login during 10 minutes.

To proceed, I need to:

- either be able to register an eventListener at the start of /login_check
- either be able to rewrite /login_check to add the event

I didn't find any event about "pre_authentication", do you have a solution ?

I won't write the code in a repository method to lad an user, it's not its place.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem a few days ago. And like you said i couldn't find a suitable "pre_authentication" either at which point i could execute my checks even before the authentication was attempted. (AuthenticationSuccess and AuthenticationFailure Handler weren't an option in my case since i wanted to block the attempt before it was even tried)

But in the end i found an approach that did work in my case (although there may be a better one but i couldn't find it).

If your application is using the default username/password authentication you could do this:

1. Extend the UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener

   ```
   class UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener extends \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener

   {
       /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
       protected $entityManager;

       /**
        * setter is called through DI container
        *
        * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
        */
       public function setEntityManager(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
       {
           $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
       }

       /**
        *
        * @param Request $request
        *
        * @return null|RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response|\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface
        */
       protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)
       {
           //do your logic and whatnot here
           // i.E. return a redirect repsonse if the token is needed but missing 

           return parent::attemptAuthentication($request);
       }

   }
   ```
2. Overwrite the original service in your services.yml

   ```
   security.authentication.listener.form:
       class: AppBundle\Listener\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener
       parent: security.authentication.listener.abstract
       abstract: true
       calls: [ [setEntityManager, ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]] ]
   ```

(Using setter injection here because the constructor needs like a ton of parameters)

Maybe this approach could fit your needs and nobody has a better idea

Comment: This is perfect ! Since i can return a response and inject my services into the listener, it's perfect. Thanks ! ;)

Comment: I dont Know why but my new Listner is not hitted, do I need to register a comaplier pass for it !